# Unable to launch weston on linux yocto from ssh

Tags: linux, yocto, wayland

I have the error *"no drm device found"* as shown below.
I thinks the mail error is fatal: failed to create compoitor backend. 
I have the following in my lib 
desktop-shell.so     drm-backend.so       fbdev-backend.so     fullscreen-shell.so  gl-renderer.so       hmi-controller.so    ivi-shell.so         wayland-backend.so   x11-backend.so

```
root@salvator-x:/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants# /usr/bin/weston-launch \
  -u root --  --idle-time=0 --config=/etc/xdg/weston/weston-drm-hdmi.ini  $OPTARGS
Date: 2018-02-26 UTC
[21:29:08.949] weston 1.11.0
               http://wayland.freedesktop.org
               Bug reports to: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Wayland&component=weston&version=1.11.0
               Build: a9df8430-dirty v4l2-renderer: Fix calcluation of clip region (2017-04-13 18:25:00 +0900)
[21:29:08.949] OS: Linux, 4.9.0-yocto-standard, #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Feb 26 17:46:03 EST 2018, aarch64
[21:29:08.949] Using config file '/etc/xdg/weston/weston-drm-hdmi.ini'
[21:29:08.950] Output repaint window is 34 ms maximum.
[21:29:08.950] Loading module '/usr/lib/weston/drm-backend.so'
[21:29:08.954] initializing drm backend
[21:29:08.954] logind: failed to get session seat
[21:29:08.954] logind: cannot setup systemd-logind helper (-61), using legacy fallback
[21:29:08.955] no drm device found
[21:29:08.955] fatal: failed to create compositor backend
failed to restore keyboard mode: Bad file descriptor
failed to set KD_TEXT mode on tty: Bad file descriptor
could not reset vt handling
```

How do I launch weston on linux yocto?

---

Here is the image:

[image]

Comment: please just dont down vote if you dont understand the question.

Comment: @jww sure. i point the code snippet of the error.. if you click on the image it expands :)

Comment: Can you provide Yocto version and target machine? What does those command returns? `bitbake -e | grep ^DISTRO_FEATURES | grep wayland` `bitbake -e <image> | egrep '^[A-Z][A-Z_]*=' | grep weston` ?

Comment: @Nayfe bitbake -e | grep  ^DISTRO_FEATURES | grep wayland returns a hit for wayland
`

Comment: the Yocto version is Poky 2.1.3

Comment: and the one for weston?

Comment: @Nayfe weston also has a hit...

Comment: target machine?

Comment: @Nayfe aarch64  is the target

Comment: Which wayland backend do you use? Do you have X11 enable? (for target, I was more thinking is it a COTS demo board?)

Comment: @Nayfe I am using drm-backend.so

Comment: i dont have x11 :( @Nayfe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So.. I found the answer to my question
it has three errors logind (systemd) was having trouble access the input keyboard type
second one is drm device is not found which implies that you have trouble accesing your output port. try to troubleshoot the port make it accessible to the board and then try to launch weston with correct config.

NOTE: Weston wayland wont launch if you dont have keyboard or a mouse connected preferably a usb